# Help me find current

Tags: current, ac

Knowing, that
$$
i_c(t)=70\sqrt{2}sin(314t+60^\circ)mA
$$
$$
R=2k
$$
$$
X_L=7k
$$
$$
X_C=7k
$$
find ir(t).
I'm sure, that the angle is -30. What about RMS?

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty high capacitance value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the current through the capacitor, you can use that to find the voltage across it, using

V<sub>C</sub> = I<sub>C</sub> Z<sub>C</sub>.

The voltage across the resistor is the same as the voltage across the capacitor.

Now you can use Ohm's law to find the current through the resistor.